# React Native SwitchSelector chnage icon color on select

Tags: react-native

```
import React from "react";
import { StatusBar, StyleSheet } from "react-native";
import { Fontisto } from "@expo/vector-icons";
import SwitchSelector from "react-native-switch-selector";

const options = [
  { label: "M", value: "M", customIcon: <Fontisto name="male" size={20} /> },
  { label: "F", value: "F", customIcon: <Fontisto name="female" size={20} /> },
];
<SwitchSelector
  options={options}
  initial={0}
  selectedColor={"#ffffff"}
  borderColor={"#cccccc"}
  buttonColor={"#539670"}
  onPress={(value) => console.log(`Call onPress with value: ${value}`)}
  selectedTextContainerStyle={{ color: "#ffffff" }}
  borderWidth="2"
/>;
```

Above code not updating icon color on option selection
need to change icon color text color change working but icon color not updated.

Comment: You need to pass color property in your Fontisto tag. You are not passing that that's why it is not changing color. For e.g.: <Fontisto name= "male" size={20} color="red">. Try like this, let me know if it didn;t work.

Comment: No not working on select it should chnage color it keep same color.

Answer (score 0):

Used react native state to changed color state on press event dynamically.

```
import { StatusBar, StyleSheet } from "react-native";
import { Fontisto } from "@expo/vector-icons";
import SwitchSelector from "react-native-switch-selector";

 handleClick = (value) => {
    let iconColourorg='';
    if(value =='M'){
         iconColourorg = 'iconColourF';
    }else{
         iconColourorg = 'iconColourM';
    }
 
    let iconColour = 'iconColour'+value;
     this.setState({
       [iconColour] : '#ffffff',
       [iconColourorg] :'#000000',
            },()=>{
            console.log(`Call onPress with value: ${value}`)
         });
}
```

```
<SwitchSelector
  options={[
  { label: 'M', value: 'M',customIcon:<Fontisto name="male" size={20}  color={this.state.iconColourM} /> },
  { label: 'F', value: 'F',customIcon:<Fontisto name="female" size={20} color={this.state.iconColourF}  />  }
         ]} 
initial={0} 
selectedColor={'#ffffff'} 
borderColor={'#cccccc'}  
buttonColor={'#539670'} 
onPress={(value) =>
  this.handleClick(value)
}  
/>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<SwitchSelector
          // textColor="red"
          selectedColor="yellow"
          buttonColor="#800000"
          borderColor="blue"
          hasPadding
          
          initial={0}
          borderRadius={20}
          //onPress={value => setGender({gender: value})}
          //options={genderOptions}
          options={[
            {
              label: 'Male',
              value: 'm',
              imageIcon: require('../images/male.png'),
            },
            {
              label: 'FeMale',
              value: 'f',
              imageIcon: require('../images/female.png'),
            },
          ]}
        />
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).